# Adding transition effect between different pages using HTML5 history API

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, transition

I'm trying to use this tutorial I found here using HTML5 history API: [Change browser url without page reloading with ajax request using JavaScript, HTML5 history API, jQuery, PHP like Facebook, Github navigation menu](http://tinywall.info/2012/02/22/change-browser-url-without-page-reload-refresh-with-ajax-request-using-javascript-html5-history-api-php-jquery-like-facebook-github-navigation-menu/#idc-container)

I can't find a way to implement a simple slide effect bewteen pages though, and I really need to do this. I tried different methods but I can't come up with a solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Start with some simple approach:

- On desired action(s) load the content into a hidden div via ajax
- Hide the previous one and slide in the div.
- maintain the history concurrently as well with each request